# Imwrite command didn't create an image with true value in Matlab

Tags: function, matlab

I'm trying to write .tif image. I wrote the following command either on command window or within function file in Matlab to write tif image with the name of 'A_exam'.

All value of output image (A_exam.tif) are 255, no image displayed, just white screen. A matrix is extracted from following code. When I calculated this code, values of A matrix are correct. The problem just comes from writing an image file.

```
[~,Ind_max] = max(vgt,[],3);
A= arrayfun(@(y) ...
arrayfun(@(x) emp(x,y, Ind_max(x,y)), 1:size(vgt,1)), ... 
1:size(vgt,2), 'UniformOutput',false);
A = reshape([A{:}], size(Ind_max))
imwrite(A,'A_exam.tif','tif')
```

Thank you

```
whos A
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         41x41             6724  single
```

Comment: Could you post an example of how the image is supposed to look like and how the results looks? Also, how did you generate Matrix A? Which type does it have?

Answer (score 0):

That reshape before calling imwrite looks problematic. I would change the

```
imwrite(A,'A_exam.tif','tif')
```

to add a call to [mat2gray](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/mat2gray.html)

```
imwrite(mat2gray(A),'A_exam.tif');
```

to make sure you're not mixing matrices and images.

Comment: The values of original A) matrix was max(A)=8.5290, min(A)=1.2830. After calculating this, The values and data type have been changed into max(A)=255, min(A)=0, type=uint8.

Comment: Still not in true value :). The expected value of output image should be between these range max(A)=8.5290, min(A)=1.2830.

Comment: @user1769107: I'm fairly certain you won't be able to save those exact values to a tiff, due to limitations of image file formats. With respect to getting only 255 this is about as good as you can do.

Comment: Oh really? It get me into another trouble. Next process will be  relational operations to find the pixel values between 7.56 and 4.29. So this would be one of the problems facing to me in matlab :) Anyway, Thank you for your help